# Grounding my 4 gang metal electrical box

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, receptacle

[image]I have a 4 gang metal electrical box with a receptacle, a fan switch, a light switch and a timer for a towel warmer.

The honeywell timer does not require to be grounded.

For the receptacle i would loop the ground wire from the "cable from source" around the screw in the box and then connect it to the receptacle.

All other grounds would go to individual screws on the box. (no screw would have more than one ground wire bound to it)

There is not much space in the box and would like to forego using a wire nut(s) if possible.

note: There are 8 screws in total in the 4 gang box.

Can i wire all the grounds to the screws as in the picture below? Would that be code in Canada?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you collapse the fan and light switches into a double switch? That'd free up quite a few in3 in the box at the cost of a faceplate change and the double switch, of course....

Comment: That's an idea,however the fan switch has a timer and the light switch is a motion detector/dimmer. Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I believe that would be CEC compliant.

Another way to go, a lot of people use crimp sleeves in crowded switch boxes to save a little space.

[image: crimp sleeve]

For this box you might do it like this:

- Wrap the receptacle cable's ground wire around a screw
- Fold all the ground wires to a point in the opposite corner
- Twist all the ground wires together and secure with a crimp ring
- Terminate ground wires on switches / receptacle grounds

The picture below is not quite what you're doing since it's a plastic box, but it gives the general idea.  It's from [this article](https://www.finehomebuilding.com/2012/05/17/how-to-wire-a-switch-box) at Fine Homebuilding.

Although this might be more ground wire in the box, it will probably fold up better - sometimes ironically with wires too short, it's actually harder to get things folded up nice and compact.

[image: box with grounds twisted and crimped]

Comment: Thanks. My thinking is the metal box ensures continuity to the electrical panel for all the grounds attached to the box screws. AND the box being sold in Canada with 8 screws in it for grounds and after talking to quite a few people and visiting quite a few websites I'm comfortable and so I did it this way and it frees up alot of space.